# Calling one ng-controller in two different html pages

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to call a controller in 2 different html files? (I think it is possible but what are the drawbacks?)

Comment: Yes, of course. Why don't you just test it? No drawback, except two different view are now coupled to the same controller.

Comment: A "drawback" is that controllers aren't singletons, so you'll get two separate controller instances. Thus changes to the scope in one view, isn't reflected in the other view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can, in you route section you can point two routes to same controller like the example below:

```
"use strict";
app.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/page1',{
        templateUrl:'views/page1.html',
        controller: pageController,
      }).when('/page2',{
        templateUrl:'views/page2.html',
        controller: pageController,
      }).otherwise({redirectTo:'/page1'});
    }
]);
```